# SwiftUI Navigation Issues, 'Group' not resolving

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, navigationlink

Environment: Xcode 11.1 running on Catalina (19A573a) and building iOS only app.

I have the following code that should be fairly simple.
- I have buttons A - H (8 buttons)
- When I tap on a button I expect to be taken to a respective view (“View A”, “View B”, etc) as they are embedded in a NavigationView.

I run into several issues
- With the code shown tapping button for “View A” does nothing but the other buttons work.
- After re-running a few times tapping on button A will work some times but fail most of the time
- If I disable displaying of all the buttons except button A tapping on button A works.
- If I disable displaying of any single button (again there are 8 buttons, A-H) then tapping on the first button works.

- I understand there is a technical limit in VStack of more than 10 view and I tried the suggestion made here:
  https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-group-views-together
  But that does not work
- I have tried variations of putting the buttons in the list and that doesn’t work.

Anyone who wants to test can create a new project and copy the entire code contents into the ContentView.swift file and run.
[image: Example]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                Spacer()

                VStack {
                    Spacer()

                    Group {
                        NavigationLink(destination: ViewA()) {
                            BasicButton(buttonName: "View A", buttonColor: .orange)
                        }

                        NavigationLink(destination: ViewB()) {
                            BasicButton(buttonName: "View B", buttonColor: .red)
                        }

                        NavigationLink(destination: ViewC()) {
                            BasicButton(buttonName: "View C", buttonColor: .green)
                        }

                        NavigationLink(destination: ViewD()) {
                            BasicButton(buttonName: "View D", buttonColor: .blue)
                        }
                    }

                    Group {
                        NavigationLink(destination: ViewE()) {
                            BasicButton(buttonName: "View E", buttonColor: .pink)
                        }

                        NavigationLink(destination: ViewF()) {
                            BasicButton(buttonName: "View F", buttonColor: .gray)
                        }

                        NavigationLink(destination: ViewG()) {
                            BasicButton(buttonName: "View G", buttonColor: .purple)
                        }

                        NavigationLink(destination: ViewH()) {
                            BasicButton(buttonName: "View H", buttonColor: .yellow)
                        }
                    }

                    Spacer()
                }

                Spacer()
            }
            .background(Color.black).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct BasicButton: View {
    var buttonName: String
    var buttonColor: Color

    var body: some View {
        Text(buttonName)
            .font(.title)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 60)
            .background(buttonColor)
            .cornerRadius(5)
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ViewA: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View A").font(.largeTitle)
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View B").font(.largeTitle)
    }
}

struct ViewC: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View C").font(.largeTitle)
    }
}

struct ViewD: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View D").font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
struct ViewE: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View E").font(.largeTitle)
    }
}

struct ViewF: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View F").font(.largeTitle)
    }
}

struct ViewG: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View G").font(.largeTitle)
    }
}

struct ViewH: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View H").font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't like this - I certainly don't - but (1) I can verify that this behavior exists on both a physical iPhone and iPad device, and (2) using `Group`, using it differently, or rearranging the order of buttons doesn't matter... no matter what, that first button doesn't navigate to the proper link. Guess what? There *is* something that works - remove the `padding` modifier in `BasicButton`. And yeah, that makes absolutely no sense to me....

Comment: I only caught that because on my iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 13.1 the top button was aligned *way* too high. (I even tried changing the frame height first but that only made the "padding" between the buttons larger.

Answer (score 0):

When you open **Debug View Hierarchy** you will notice that View A is completely obstructed by a invisible NavigationBar, which even though it is invisible is blocking all the touches from reaching View A.

[image: View Hierarchy]